# How to detect open CAN bus using CAN socket in C

Tags: c, linux, sockets, can-bus

I will try to keep it short. I have a C application which opens can socket port using the following approach
...

```
struct sockaddr_can lCanAddr;
struct ifreq lIfr;

if ((*aCanSocket = socket(PF_CAN, SOCK_RAW, CAN_RAW)) < 0) {
    log_error("socket not created");
    return -1;
}
strcpy(lIfr.ifr_name, CANSOCKETNAME);
ioctl(*aCanSocket, SIOCGIFINDEX, &lIfr);
lCanAddr.can_family = AF_CAN;
lCanAddr.can_ifindex = lIfr.ifr_ifindex;
```

....

How can I detect the following cases:

1. when the CAN bus is broken or no device connected to the CAN port
2. CAN bus off error
   I tried some approach by trying to read or write the socket regularly but that does not throw me any error. Can anyone suggest me a way of detecting this cases. I am using C for the implementation. Thanks for the time and patience.

Comment: I added Linux as tag since I assume that's the socket lib you are referring to.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any idea regarding the issue

Comment: Never used that lib, can't help you.

Comment: The "library" is the [SocketCAN](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/can.txt) API of Linux. You can use the `socketcan` tag for questions about it.

Answer (score 1):

[SocketCAN](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/can.txt) uses error frames to report CAN bus errors. These are special `can_frame`s with bit 0x20000000 set in the `can_id`. The other bits in `can_id`, and the bytes in `data`, contain information about the error(s). See `<linux/can/error.h>` for more information.

To receive error frames, you first have to enable them. SocketCAN supports filtering them, but the easiest is to just enable them all:

```
can_err_mask_t optval = CAN_ERR_MASK;
setsockopt(*aCanSocket, SOL_CAN_RAW, CAN_RAW_ERR_FILTER, &optval, sizeof(optval));
```

Every time you read a CAN frame, you first have to check if it is an error frame or a normal data frame.

In general, you will not receive error frames until you try to send a CAN frame. In the case of a broken CAN bus, this will typically quickly lead to a bus-off error. You can detect this when you receive an error frame with bit 0x040 (`CAN_ERR_BUSOFF`) set in `can_id`.

I'm not sure if you'll receive an error frame if no device is connected to the bus. But there may be another way to check for that, if the driver supports it. If no other device is present on the bus, the ACK bit of a sent frame will not be cleared, which is something the CAN controller can detect. If the driver considers unacknowledged frames as not sent, you can detect this in your application. First, you have to set some options so you receive all the frames you send:

```
setsockopt(*aCanSocket, SOL_CAN_RAW, CAN_RAW_LOOPBACK, &(int){ 1 }, sizeof(int));
setsockopt(*aCanSocket, SOL_CAN_RAW, CAN_RAW_RECV_OWN_MSGS, &(int){ 1 }, sizeof(int));
```

Second, you have to use `recvmsg()` to read the CAN frames so you can check the `msg_flags` member of the `msghdr` struct. If it contains the `MSG_CONFIRM` flag, it is a transmission confirmation. It indicates that that frame was successfully sent by the socket on which you received it. You can use this to detect the presence of other devices on the CAN bus. If you send a frame and receive a confirmation, other devices are present. If you never receive the confirmation, you're the only device on the bus (or there is some other problem).

Comment: Thanks for your time and answer. I am also trying to catch the Error active and Error passive state along with Buss OFF. I am checking CAN_ERR_CRTL_RX_PASSIVE and CAN_ERR_CRTL_TX_PASSIVE for passive error. CAN_ERR_PROT_ACTIVE for active error. Is this the correct check for active and passive error?

Comment: You're correct about the passive state. For the active state you need to check if the `CAN_ERR_CRTL_ACTIVE` bit is set in `data[1]`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am facing an issue to with the BUS OFF state. When more than one device is connected in the bus I receive a BUS OFF state. I am checking the BUS OFF state:  (lTempFrame).can_id & CAN_ERR_BUSOFF. Is this wrong?

Comment: That probably means that the bit rates of the devices are not the same.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Do you have any idea what can be reason for PDO response missing or remote request response missing when multiple devices are connected within a bus?